# Difference between Meta-Analysis, Meta-Regression and Moderator-Analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

What is the difference between the classic meta-analysis (that aggregates effect sizes from a sample of studies to a summary effect size), meta-regression analysis and moderator analysis?

As I understood moderator analysis is used to explain heterogeneity in a meta-analysis by regressing a vector containing the effect sizes of each study on specific variables that could explain the heterogeneity (e.g. publication year,...). But what's the difference between moderator-analysis and meta-regression?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question could be improved by providing a citation or two pertinent to "meta-regression" and, perhaps to the use of moderator analysis within the meta-regression context. While effect moderation (aka effect modification aka interaction effects) is common enough in applied data analysis, I wonder if you are interested in a very specific kind of application? The "edit" link in the lower left of your question can be used for you to clarify your question along these lines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for definitions that may help to clarify the terminology:

- **Meta-analysis**: A general term to denote the collection of statistical methods and techniques used to aggregate/synthesize and compare the results from several related studies in a systematic manner.
- **Moderator analysis**: In the context of a meta-analysis, this refers to using some kind of method in an attempt to find and account for systematic differences in the size of the effect or outcome that is being meta-analyzed.
- **Meta-regression**: This is one possible way of conducting a moderator analysis, where we regress the observed effect sizes on one or multiple study characteristics.

There are other ways of conducting a moderator analysis. For example, one could simply subgroup studies based on a categorical moderator (using dummy variables in a meta-regression model is quite similar). Not commonly used, but one could also consider mixture models or clustering techniques.